# JQuery .scrollLeft() не работает после .prepend()

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

```js
 var scroll = $('#scrollTable').scrollLeft();

 $.get('/monitor/sortajax', param).done(function(data){
               
                $('#content').prepend(data); 
                
                var fg = $(data).find('#scrollTable');

$(fg).scrollLeft(scroll); //не скролит
                 $('#scrollTable').scrollLeft(scroll);//так тоже не скролит

            });
```

Смотрел в отладчике, как я понял скролл не работает потому что $.isWindow( $('#scrollTable')) возвращает false. Дело в том что данный код успешно работал, теперь перестал. Узел '#scrollTable' находит.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не работает после prepend()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var fg = $(data).find('#scrollTable');

Вероятно, это не тот объект, который был добавлен.
И не надо оборачивать второй раз jQuery-наборы.

```
data = $(data);
$('#content').prepend(data);
var fg = data.find('#scrollTable');
fg.scrollLeft(scroll);
```

---

Такой вариант должен заставить браузер пересчитать расположение элементов:

```
data = $(data);
$('#content').prepend(data);
var fg = data.find('#scrollTable');
//BEGIN: Одна или несколько следующих строк должны помочь:
data.width();
data.parent().width();
$('body').toggleClass('force-css-recalculation');
$('body').width();
//END
fg.scrollLeft(scroll);
```

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость! Спасибо за совет. Оказалось проблема в том что узел '#scrollTable' не успевает заполнится элементами и поэтому скролить нечего. Я проверил это, с помощью setTimeout(function(){var el = document.getElementById('scrollTable');
    el.scrollTo(200, 0);}, 4000); Через 4 секунды работает.

Comment: @andatr, а мой вариант тоже не работает?

Comment: Проверил Ваш вариант, так как причина в том что "скролить нечего", ваш вариант дает такой же результат, то есть не скролит

Comment: @andatr, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось проблема в том что узел '#scrollTable' не успевает заполнится элементами и поэтому скролить нечего. Я проверил это, с помощью

```js
 setTimeout(function(){
   var el = document.getElementById('scrollTable'); el.scrollTo(200, 0);
}, 4000);
```

Через 4 секунды работает

Comment: По идее, можно заставить браузер принудительно пересчитать размеры. Или у тебя в него содержимое потом добавляется?

Comment: Содержимое находится в data, то есть  $('#content').prepend(data); вставляет все что нужно. После этого ничего не добавляется.